# Basics: Query results not returning as expected

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have less than basic knowledge of MS Access, as I only need to use it to pull down information irregularly before using R to do the manipulation. As a result, I have no SQL coding knowledge - I just use the Access GUI.

**My problem**: When I create a query that includes multiple tables Access seems to exclude the results that don't have values in all of the tables.

**Solution**: I'm looking for a simple way, through the GUI, to tell Access to include all the IDs in the parent table, irrespective of whether they have values in any of the child tables. Those IDs that have no values in the child tables should just return with blanks in those columns.

I know this is probably SQL 101 but my searching hasn't returned anything useful.

Comment: `FROM tblParent AS p LEFT JOIN tblChild AS c ON p.ID = c.ID`  If you need to see how to accomplish that from the query designer's Design View, look under the *"Show all rows from one table, and corresponding rows from the other table"* heading at [Join tables and queries](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Join-tables-and-queries-3f5838bd-24a0-4832-9bc1-07061a1478f6#bmouter)

Comment: Thanks, @HansUp, the properties of the join in design view worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN, the direction meaning the table from which you want to get all rows. See the select below:

SELECT * FROM TABLE_A a LEFT JOIN TABLE_B b ON a.id=b.id

This will return all rows from TABLE_A linked to the corresponding rows from TABLE_B. When there is no match the TABLE_B columns will return NULL.